# Part of new privilege notification text is in Russian

Tags: bug, user-interface, notifications, top-bar, localization

I just got a notification that I'd earned a new site privilege.  For some reason, though, part of the notification text is in Russian, not English:

[image: Screenshot of Achievements drop-down menu with random Russian text]

Apparently it says "Узнайте больше об этом в Справке," which means (more or less) "Learn more about it in the Help Center."  I assume somebody probably just mixed up the translations.

Comment: For a moment I thought that it might be some kind of [Easter egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)), if it is from [linguistics.se]. But then I realized that L stands for [law.se].

Comment: Easter Egg Bug.